# Invalid handle attempting to load message from resource DLL

Tags: transactional

We are doing SQL Server Transactional Publication through C# code between SQL Server 2005 and SQL Express 2005. It is working in couple of laptops, but in some laptops it is giving error as:

> Invalid handle attempting to load message from resource DLL

Can someone help me why we are getting this error and how can we solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I came across this same issue while experimenting with RMO merge pull subscriptions. In my case the folder I had specified for the merge agent log didn't exists, or the current user didn't have permission to write to that folder.

subscription.SynchronizationAgent.Output = "C:\TEMP\mergeagent.log";